# AWS Lambda: Handling variable input types

Tags: aws-lambda

What's the standard means of processing input to an AWS Lambda handler function, when the format of the incoming JSON varies depending on the type of trigger?

e.g. I have a Lambda function that gets called when an object is created in an S3 bucket, *or* when an hourly scheduled event fires.  Obviously, the JSON passed to the handler is formatted differently.

Is it acceptable to overload Lambda handler functions, with the input type defined as `S3Event` for one signature and `ScheduledEvent` for the other?  If not, are developers simply calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` in `try` blocks?  Or is the standard practice to establish multiple Lambda functions, one for each input type (yuck!)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use one function per event.

Having multiple triggers for one Lambda will just make things way harder, as you'll end up with a bunch of if/else, switch statements or even Factory methods if you want to apply design patterns.

Now think of Lambda functions as small and maintainable. Think of pieces of code that should do one thing and should do it well. By the moment you start having multiple triggers, you kind of end up with a "Lambda Monolith", as it will have way too many responsibilities. Not only that, you strongly couple your Lambda functions with your events, meaning that once a new trigger is added, your Lambda code should change. This is just not scalable after two or three triggers.

Another drawback is that you are bound to using one language only if you architect it like that. For some use cases, Java may be the best option. But for others, it may be Node JS, Python, Go...

Essentially, your functions should be small enough to be easily maintainable and even rewritten if necessary. There's absolutely nothing wrong with creating one function per event, although, apparently, you strongly disapprove it. Think of every Lambda as a separate Microservice, which scales out independently, has its own CI/CD pipeline and its own suite of tests.

Another thing to consider is if you want to limit your Lambda concurrent executions depending on your trigger type. This would be unachievable via the "One-Lambda-Does-It-All" model.

Stick with one Lambda per trigger and you'll sleep better at night.

Comment: Well, the scenario of conditional statements to handle the different input types would be addressed by overloading the handler method, which is why I asked about that approach.  Also, I'm using F#, which is rather good at processing input into associated yet distinct types, but I'll take your answer into advisement.  Thanks.

Comment: What exactly you don't like about one lambda per trigger?

Comment: Generally, I think that one Lambda per trigger type is fine.  F# has excellent support for unions, though, so it would be nice to take advantage of different triggers as union types -- especially where minimal processing occurs before the code resolves into something uniform for all of types expected by the Lambda function.  (e.g. In addition to processing objects placed into my S3 bucket, I might want my Lambda to log something hourly.  Creating a whole new Lambda just for that purpose means an increase in complexity that isn't commensurate with the slight increase in functionality.)

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible by doing the following:

1. Have the Lambda signature take a `Stream` rather than the Amazon event type, so we can get the raw JSON message.
2. Read the JSON contents of the stream as a string.
3. Deserialize the string to a custom type in order to identify the event source.
4. Use the event source information to deserialize the JSON a second time to the appropriate type for the event source.

For example:

```cs
public async Task FunctionHandler(Stream stream, ILambdaContext context)
{
    using var streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
    var json = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

    var serializationOptions = new JsonSerializationOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
    var awsEvent = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AwsEvent>(json, serializationOptions);
    var eventSource = awsEvent?.Records.Select(e => e.EventSource).SingleOrDefault();
         
    await (eventSource switch
    {
        "aws:s3" => HandleAsync(Deserialize<S3Event>(json, serializationOptions), context),
        "aws:sqs" => HandleAsync(Deserialize<SQSEvent>(json, serializationOptions), context),
        _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof (stream), $"Unsupported event source '{eventSource}'."),
    });
}

public async Task HandlyAsync(S3Event @event) => ...
public async Task HandleAsync(SQSEvent @event) => ...

public sealed class AwsEvent
{
    public List<Record> Records { get; set; }

    public sealed class Record
    {
        public string EventSource { get; set; }
    }
}
```